# CSS height in terms of line-height

Tags: css

Using CSS, how can I size a box's height in terms of its (or its parent's) line-height?

This would allow easily making regions of text an exact multiple of a number of lines, e.g. to allow showing exactly three lines.

I don't want a javascript solution as those are generally slow and interact poorly with dynamically re-rendered layouts.

**Edit:**  The line-heights in my case are specified in unit-less numbers, as [recommended on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Notes), so it'd be handy if line-height units weren't required to get this to work.

Comment: If you are not using JavaScript then you will have to hard code the numbers. Setting something like that should not be slow in JavaScript.

Comment: In SASS you will be able to multiply such related values in any proportions you need.

Comment: @keaukraine could you post an answer with a solution to this in SASS? I'm interested in this as well. What about dynamic heights?

Comment: @DarkAshelin, On that case the change should interact with the script some how. I dont think this is possible without the script.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interacting with the page without an interactive script.

Comment: @Starx: (A) interacting with the page or not does not pertain to being on-topic in any way.  (B) This is similar to setting box width in terms of `em` -  you don't need to "interact", simply to define.

Comment: I was slow enough for somebody else to provide SASS example :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I've entirely understood the question, but couldn't you just use relative units - ems?

If the line height is, for example, 2ems (or unitless) and you want the total height of the box to be 3 "lines" high (presumably not taking into account padding) then you could set the height to be 6ems. This way, the line height is flexible based on your base unit (font size) and the height will also be fluid using the same base unit.

Here's an example:

```
.myBox {
     line-height: 2; // this will be twice the value of the font-size
     height: 6ems; // equivalent to 3 lines high
```

To achieve the same thing in SASS you could write:

```
$lineheight: 2; // this value can be unitless or a unit like ems, px or percentage
$numberoflines: 3; 
.myBox {
    line-height: $lineheight;
    height: $lineheight * $numberoflines;
}
```

This would have the flexibility for you to move your variables into a settings file so that you (or someone else) can easily alter the values without having to find all the selectors that use the variables.

Comment: Typically, line-height is in unitless numbers that represent a multiple of the font-size.  Using an united line-height like in your example is nasty because it means that you no longer get automatic scaling of line-height with font-size, so basically you know need to manually set lineheight *everywhere* you change the font-size even though the browser's own computation is actually better, since it does so automatically, and can even compensate for font-fallbacks via font-size-adjust.

Comment: However, the approach is sound; especially if you use the `ex` unit which is probably the one you want, here.  Maybe `ex` in combination with `font-size-adjust`?

Comment: I agree that you normally wouldn't want to use units like pixels but it was simply to demonstrate how SASS could compute. SASS doesn't care what the units are or if indeed there are any at all.

Comment: However, I disagree that line-height is usually unitless. It is often set using ems in order I establish good vertical rhythm. See here: http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/

Comment: Unitless line-heights are exactly the same as `em`s in normal text (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height); and when font-sizes change, I'd prefer the line-height to scale naturally rather than change the proportion of the text-to-line-spacing (but if you prefer to change proportions to maintain a fixed rhythm, `em` would be better).  In practice they're usually the same anyhow. But that means I'm in luck-if I know the line height in unitless numbers I can set the box-height in em's and get exactly what I want! And with line-height in `em`s it's only slightly harder!

Comment: +1; if you add an example with unitless numbers, your answer would cover all bases.

Comment: Interesting link. I didn't realise that ems and percentages inherited badly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive discussion!  I love how simple the answer is, in the end :-).  BTW, I'm not a sass expert, but the [online interpreter](http://sass-lang.com/try.html) suggests you'd need to do something like `height: $lineheight * $numberoflines * 1em;` to make sure the height *does* have a unit.

Answer (score 9):

The Level 4 spec for CSS values now defines a new unit called `lh`. However, it is still not widely supported at the time of writing.

It's also worth mentioning that a `rlh` unit is available which behaves the same way as the rem unit.

With this new unit you could do something like this to show only 3 lines of text for example.

```
.wrapper {
  height: 3lh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant news; thanks for the heads up!  Looks like only firefox is still missing the unit, and this appears to be the tracking issue concerning its implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1310170

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround I used

```html
<div style="display: flex; border: 1px solid red">
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div>
        This text will appear in a box that has a height of at least 3 lines.
    </div>
</div>
```